# Converting SQl query into redshift

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift

I have query for month to date statement in SQL and to convert it into redshift. Can someone please help me converting below case statement from SQL Server to redshift?

SQL query :

```
CASE WHEN day(weekenddate) <= 7 THEN dateadd(dd, - day(dateadd(dd, - day(weekenddate), weekenddate)) + 1, dateadd(dd, - day(weekenddate), weekenddate)) 
ELSE dateadd(dd, - day(weekenddate) + 1, weekenddate) END AS MTDStartDateTY,
```

Comment: `day(<date>)` will be replaced with `date_part(d, <date>)` and `dateadd(dd, <date1>, <date2>)` will be replaced with `dateadd(d, <date1>, <date2>)`. So there really isn't anything too tricky here

Answer (score 1):

Here is the conversion

```
case when date_part(d, weekenddate)<= 7 THEN dateadd(day, - date_part(d,dateadd(day, - date_part(d, weekenddate), weekenddate)) + 1, dateadd(day, - date_part(d, weekenddate), weekenddate)) 
ELSE dateadd(day, - date_part(d, weekenddate) + 1, weekenddate) END AS MTDStartDateTY,
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, when i try that  i am getting the below error.[Code: 500310, SQL State: 42883]  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", double precision, date) does not exist;